# Create a war file including external jars using command prompt

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I have two projects - Project1 and Project2. Project1 contains all the java classes. And project2 contains all the jar files required in project1. Means, Project1 depends on Project1 (for jars).

I am using Glassfish server. While creating the war file of Project1, I included all the jar files from project2.

**Example:**
Project2 conatins 2 packages - POI and web-services.
**POI package contains:** 
poi-examples-3.6-20091214.jar,
poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar, 
poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar, 
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar,
 poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar.

**web-services package contains:**
 javax.servlet-3.0.jar,
 javax.servlet-api.jar, 
jersey-bundle-1.10.jar, 
jersey-client-1.12.jar,
 jersey-core-1.12.jar,
 jersey-multipart-1.4.jar.

Now for creating the war file for Project1 from command prompt, I used the following command:

```
jar cvf Project1.war D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-examples-3.6-20091214.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\javax.servlet-3.0.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\javax.servlet-api.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\jersey-bundle-1.10.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\jersey-client-1.12.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\jersey-core-1.12.jar D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\web-services\jersey-multipart-1.4.jar
```

Project1.war file created in the current directory.
But, when I tried to deploy the Project1.war on Glassfish server, I encountered this error:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\Project1\D:\JavaProject\Project2\lib\external\poi\poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar
```

*(C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\ is the directory where '.war' files are copied after deployment)*

I could not understand the problem. Is something wrong with the command, I executed for creating war file? How are external jars included while creating war file using command line prompt?

Please help.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will java do with that command ?

Comment: @Baadshah: The command will create the war file which can be deployed on Glassfish server.

Comment: ... and will do so improperly, as you are finding

Comment: Yes. I'm not getting how to write the command to fulfill the condition.

Answer (score 1):

A WAR file has to have a specific file structure.

```
/   
    META-INF/
    WEB-INF/
        classes/
             classes and other classpath resources go here
        lib/
             jar files go here
        web.xml
    other webapp stuff; e.g. HTML, JSPs, CSS ...
```

If you just throw stuff into a JAR file at random, it won't be recognizable as a webapp when it is unpacked by the webapp container.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [WAR exploded layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29), in other words, project2 should be included at $PROJECT1_DEPLOYMENT_DIR/WEB-INF/lib and so on. Then your jar command will result in a deployable file to Glassfish or any other servlet container.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I've included all the jar file in the CLASSPATH already. Is that what you mean?